# Transfer data between two forms without creating new instance again

Tags: c#, winforms

We can transfer data from Form1 to Form2 whit this code:

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
frm2.textBox1.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
frm2Show();
```

Now i want send data back to Form1 without creating new instance, How it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*One* way is to add a property to `Form1`, then pass the instance of `Form1` to `Form2` in the constructor.  `Form2` can then access the property of `Form1` to set the data.  However this tightly couples `Form1` and `Form2`, which may be a bad thing.

A *better* way to do this is to declare an `event` and a custom event handler in `Form2` that `Form1` subscribes to.  The custom event handler can have a property that contains the data you want to send back to `Form1`.

Form2:

```
public event EventHandler<Form2EventArgs> Form2Event;

public class Form2EventArgs : EventArgs
{
    // for illustration only:
    // do NOT use `object` and to NOT call it `Data`
    public object Data {get;set;}
}
```

Event listener in Form1:

```
private void GetData(object sender, Form2EventArgs args)
{
    object data = args.Data;
    // do something with the data
}
```

Subscribing to the event:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();

form2.Form2Event += GetData;
```

Firing the event:

```
object data = ///  blah
if(Form2Event != null)
    Form2Event(this, new Form2EventArgs {Data = data});
```

Answer (score 0):

easily you can solve this out using delegate with event...

```
    public delegate void DataSender(object dataObject);
    public event DataSender dataSender;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataSender("Pass your Data object");
    }
```

now within the Form1 you should subscribe that delegate which is created on form2

```
   public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        Subscribe(form2);
        form2.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void Subscribe(Form2 form2)
    {
        form2.dataSender += new Form2.DataSender(GetDataFromForm2);
    }

    private void GetDataFromForm2(object dataObject)
    {
        // Do somthing with data 
    }
```